# replace logical elements in a list based on another logical list in R

Tags: r, list, function, nested-loops

I am trying to change the logical values (elements) of my list based on another list. Basically, where both lists are "TRUE", I want to change the value in the main list to "FALSE". Both lists are lengths of 5. For example

```
List_A <- list(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE),c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))

List_B <-list(c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE))
```

List B has sequences as name attributes.

Desired output:

```
Output <-
list(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE))
```

In other words, elements in listA remain the same unless they have matching TRUE values in both lists, which replaces them to FALSE.
I've tried running the for loop below but it doesn't work and I don't know how I would redirect the output, if it did.

`for(i in 1:length(List_A)) { List_A[[i]][List_B[[i]]] <- FALSE }`

Comment: Is there a reason to not turn these lists into matrices? That would make it unnecessary to use a loop (and `Map` is also a loop).

Comment: Thank you! The map function works great. I have a downstream function that requires the input to be lists, which is why I working with them like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take help of `Map` function.

If both the values are `TRUE` turn to `FALSE` or keep value from `List_A`.

```
Output <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x & y, FALSE), List_A, List_B)
Output
#[[1]]
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

#[[2]]
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

#[[3]]
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE

#[[4]]
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

#[[5]]
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**data**

```
List_A <- list(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE),c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))
List_B <- list(c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This worked great. However, the output is not as accurate as I would like. I only want elements with TRUE in both lists to be replaced with FALSE. If the match is "FALSE", I would like it to remain FALSE. How can I do this? I've updated the question to show the desired result

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(List_A, List_B, ~ !(.x & .y))
```

#### data

```
List_A <- list(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE),c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))
List_B <- list(c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. If I only want to change matching TRUE values to FALSE and leave the rest as they are in ListA, how can I tweak the code?

Comment: @user15520242 in that case just do `map2(List_A, List_B,  `&`)` the `&` within backquotes

Comment: Actually this still gives the same output as `~ !(.x & .y)`, except that total counts for TRUE have been swapped with FALSE. However, if I replace it with the function from @ronak above, then it gives the expected output. Thank you regardless!